# Dot product in cylidrical coordinates

Tags: vectors, differentiation, calculus

I'm given the vector:

$$\vec{V}{(r,θ,z)}=\frac{1}{r}\hat{e_r} + (r\cosθ)\hat{e_θ}+\frac{z^2}{r^2}\hat{e_z}$$

I want the scalar product ${\vec{\nabla}}\cdot{\vec{V}}$

We know that in cylindrical coordinates : $$\vec{\nabla}=\left<\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial θ},\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right>$$

So , the product should be 
$${\vec{\nabla}}\cdot{\vec{V}} =\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial θ}(r\cosθ)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{z^2}{r^2}\right) = -\frac{1}{r^2}-\sinθ +\frac{2z}{r^2}$$

However , in the answers , the answer given is this : 
$${\vec{\nabla}}\cdot{\vec{V}}=\frac{1}{r}\Big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(1)+\frac{\partial}{\partial θ}(r\cosθ)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(z^2)\Big\}=-\sinθ+\frac{2z}{r^2}$$

I don't understand why $\frac{1}{r}$ was factored out and how is that possible. I understand you can factor it out for the partial derivative with respect to $θ$ and $z$ but in the first one, which is with respect to $r$, it shouldn't be factored out, it should be differentiated. Any thoughts? Am I missing something or is there a typo in the answers?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a typo..

Comment: @KevinDeNotariis That sounds like it should be an answer

Comment: <Side Note> when typing math, use `\sin` (example $\sin(x)$) as opposed to `sin` (example $sin(x)$). Math functions need to be upright characters to distringuish them from variables that are slanted.

Comment: Turns out it's not a typo. Check this video out if you want to know why : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yS1gfxrmWh8 . The del operator changes in cylidrical coordinates more than what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [divergence operator in cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) is actually different from what you believe it to be:
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf A=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r A_r\right)+\frac{1}{r}\,\frac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}
$$
You seem to be confusing it with the gradient operator, which as the form you specify:
$$
\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\hat{r}+\frac{1}{r}\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\hat{z}
$$
(though obviously you're ignoring the unit vectors).